# Use SDK 10.5 in Xcode 4.1 on Lion

Tags: macos, xcode, leopard

I just upgraded my machine to Lion to see if the project works on the new OS, but I else need to support users using the program on machines running OS X 10.5, but Xcode 4.1 doesn't come with the 10.5 SDK, where can I get the SDK & how do I install it on my system?

Comment: Read this, some good info. You can install Xcode 3.2.6 on Lion it seems. http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/305884-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion.html

Comment: I thought there was an option to install the 10.5 SDK when installing Xcode, but perhaps I'm wrong...

Comment: @jtbandes there was an option to install previous SDKs when installing Xcode....that feature was dropped in Xcode 4.1 TT.TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the disk image of xcode 3 (latest version) & found MacOSX10.5.pkg under packages & installed it in the Developer folder, it works great for the majority of stuff (had some problems with a C++ Library but managed to work around it)

Answer (score 1):

That SDK isn't "supported" by Apple on that version of Xcode. You can still try Xcode 3.2.6 on Lion http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/305884-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion.html to avoid keeping around Snow Leopard for the "supported" version.